# How to configure nested objects from appsettings.json in .NET Core?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

VS2015 Pro, .NET Core, Web Application.

I'm trying to figure out how to get objects out of appsettings, that have nested objects. I can do it with single level objects by creating a POCO with simple types that match the config names. But with more complex objects, it's not working. I'm getting top level objects back, but they are coming back null. Here's what I have so far:

StartUp.ConfigureServices:

[image]

appsettings.json:

[image]

POCO APIContext:

[image]

Using Class:

[image]

So I get my three API objects back but they are all null.
I don't know enough about the Configuration in Startup.cs to know what it's supposed to look like, but here it is.

[image]

Comment: What are the errors you are experiencing?

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof Sorry, I made some changes mid typing of that question. No more errors, but I updated the question to show that my API objects are coming back null.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the `Configure` method in your `Startup` and check the `IConfiguration`? Verify that all the settings are loaded correctly

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof I added an image of my configuration members, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to look to begin with.

Comment: Please don't make code screenshots. Use copy-paste and code formatting instead. It is much easier to read and reproduce.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nested options are supported and successfully deserialized from `appsettings.json`. However, fields instead of properties break built-in POCO object deserialization. With the properties the problem should disappear:

```cs
public API FirstAPI { get; set; }

public string Path { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. And sorry about the screenshots, I will correct that on future posts.