# How to validate a C# nested Options class?

Tags: c#

Using the [C# Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837564/how-to-configure-nested-objects-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core) question/answer as example.

I've decided to move the options from their original place at the `AnkiOptions` class to a nested `LocalPath` class. I've done this in order to separate different configs into their own logical groups while also being able to receive a single Option instance from the DI. I do have a feel that this increases the coupling between the option sections. So if that goes against the Options pattern remarks are welcome.

With having the following `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Anki": {
    "LocalPath": {
      "LastDuplicateTimestampCheckFile": "./anki-db-files/last-duplicate-check",
      "MainDbCollectionFile": "./anki-db-files/collection.anki2",
      "WalFile": "./anki-db-files/collection.anki2-wal"
    }
  }
}
```

Having an `AnkiOptions` class:

```
public sealed class AnkiOptions
{
    public const string AnkiOptionsConfigSection = "Anki";

    public LocalPath LocalPath { get; set; }
}
```

And a `LocalPath` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class LocalPath
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string LastDuplicateTimestampCheckFile { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string MainDbCollectionFile { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string WalFile { get; set; }
}
```

When the options were inside the `AnkiOptions` class the way i validated them was the following:

```
services
       .AddOptions<AnkiOptions>()
       .Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(AnkiOptions.AnkiOptionsConfigSection))
       .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

How do i validate the options in `LocalPath`? Shall i register `LocalPath` as an option and request it from DI in the constructor of the `AnkiOptions` class? Not sure if that'll work. Or is there some other way to validate nested options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build-in options validator does not support nested objects - see [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36093). You have several options.

Add `Validate` call:

```
services
    .AddOptions<AnkiOptions>()
    .Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(AnkiOptions.AnkiOptionsConfigSection))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .Validate(
        opts => Validator.TryValidateObject(opts.LocalPath, new ValidationContext(opts.LocalPath), new List<ValidationResult>()), 
        "LocalPath is invalid")
```

I was not able to add a more meaningful message via it.

Implement `IValidatableObject`. Something like the following to start (can be improved, for example to handle property paths correctly):

```
public sealed class AnkiOptions : IValidatableObject
{
   // ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this.LocalPath, new ValidationContext(this.LocalPath), validationResults);
        return validationResults;
    }
}
```

Use 3rd party library, for example [MiniValidation as described by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/validating-nested-dataannotation-options-recursively-with-minivalidation/#validating-ioptions-with-minivalidation):

```
public class MiniValidationValidateOptions<TOptions>
    : IValidateOptions<TOptions> where TOptions : class
{
    public MiniValidationValidateOptions(string? name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string? Name { get; }

    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string? name, TOptions options)
    {
        // Null name is used to configure ALL named options, so always applys.
        if (Name != null && Name != name)
        {
            // Ignored if not validating this instance.
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Skip;
        }

        // Ensure options are provided to validate against
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options);

        //  MiniValidation validation 
        if (MiniValidator.TryValidate(options, out var validationErrors))
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
        }

        string typeName = options.GetType().Name;
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var (member, memberErrors) in validationErrors)
        {
            errors.Add($"DataAnnotation validation failed for '{typeName}' member: '{member}' with errors: '{string.Join("', '", memberErrors)}'.");
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(errors);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
services
    .AddOptions<AnkiOptions>()
    .Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(AnkiOptions.AnkiOptionsConfigSection))
    .ValidateViaMiniValidation();


public static class MiniValidationExtensions
{
    public static OptionsBuilder<TOptions> ValidateViaMiniValidation<TOptions>(
        this OptionsBuilder<TOptions> optionsBuilder) where TOptions : class
    {
        //  register the validator against the options
        optionsBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<TOptions>>(
            new MiniValidationValidateOptions<TOptions>(optionsBuilder.Name));
        return optionsBuilder;
    }
}
```